# empty result from pyspark script

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spark-streaming

```
kvs = KafkaUtils.createStream(ssc, zkQuorum, "spark-streaming-consumer", {topic: 1})
lines = kvs.map(lambda x: x[1])
words = lines.flatMap(lambda line: line.split(" "))
pairs = words.map(lambda word: (word, 1))
wordCounts = pairs.reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + y)

print("===============================================================")
wordCounts.pprint()
print("================================================================")
```

`

When i run the script not getting the output, only prints below two lines and nothing in between.

================================================================

**empty here**

================================================================

Comment: tried wordCounts.pprint(num=20) too but still no result.

Comment: print wordCounts.pprint()
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: print wordCounts.count()
                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: ok .. and `wordCounts.count()` ?

Comment: nothing, just empty.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/146055/discussion-between-yaron-and-codepiper).

Comment: There was issue with data stream. Thanks @Yaron